# Syntax Error on Grunt Build

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Why am I getting this error if my code is definitely right? Grunt is prompting error:

> c:\xampp\htdocs\yeoman\ci-test\Grunt
>       < % if(includeLess) { % >
>       ^ Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>   >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on build

Code:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', [
    <% if(includeLess) { %>
    'less',<% } %>
    'express',
    'open',
    'imagemin',
    'watch'
]);
```

Comment: under default server settings, I doubt your `gruntfile.js` can compile `<% if(includeLess) { %>` as it's just a plain text JavaScript file.

Comment: thanks Jamie what will i do to be able to create if else statement?

Comment: I'm a PHP Developer, but I'm pretty sure you'd need to somehow generate this using in asp file. The file isn't touched by the ASP processor before sending it to the client, so the ASP doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%` and `%>` are opening and closing statements for lodash templates: http://lodash.com/docs#template which Grunt uses within the config.

The templates are just strings, meaning they must be wrapped in `'` or `"` and processed with `grunt.template.process`: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template#grunt.template.process or when included within the Grunt config, they're process automatically.

But since Gruntfiles are javascript, you don't need to leverage lodash templates in that portion of the Gruntfile. Just use javascript:

```
var tasks = ['express', 'open', 'imagemin', 'watch'];
if (includeLess) tasks.unshift('less'); // add less to the beginning of array
grunt.registerTask('serve', tasks);
```

Comment: i got an error includeLess is not defined but includeLess is within my  index.js why cant it see that variable?

Comment: The variable `includeLess` needs to be in your Gruntfile. JavaScript can only access variables within scope. Another option is to switch it for `if (grunt.option('include-less')) tasks.unshift('less')` and when you run grunt with the option: `grunt serve --include-less` it will prepend the less task.

Comment: Thanks kyle fixed it .. last thing if i have a variable includeLess in my index.js how can i pass it to my grunt.js? this is a yeoman generator im doing

Comment: You can export it with `exports.includeLess = includeLess` and then require it within your gruntfile: `var includeLess = require('./index.js').includeLess;` Although chances are your index.js file and Gruntfile shouldn't really be talking to each other but I don't know the purpose of your index.js file.